# C++ complilation problems in VS2010 Beta 1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Well, I've recently installed VS2010 and I'm having a problem with simple C++ applications compilation.
If I create a project that's named WW and I compile it and everything works fine, then If I opened an old project, and try to compile it, VS will compile WW!

Other times, I try to debug the application and it refueses to do so. The green debug button gets disabled.

Can you solve that?

Comment: Beta 2 has been released a while ago (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd582936.aspx) - you should really consider trying that first, since there was a large number of bug fixes between beta 1 and beta 2, and your case may well be covered by one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you inadvertently open the old project into your current solution that includes WW as the default project?

Comment: Because the default project will be the one that is compiled and run when you hit the green play button.  You need to create a whole new solution for your new projects.  A solution is something you use to group many related or dependent projects, not unrelated new projects.

You can also change the default project in the solution to whichever project you are trying to debug, then the green play button should work how you expect.

If I am missing something here, let me know.